# Find the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{9\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We have to solve the following integration.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x}{9\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}} dx$$

In this I replaced $x$ by $\pi - x$

But after that, I got stuck.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$I =\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {x }{9\cos ^2 x+\sin ^2 x} dx =\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac {\pi-x}{9\cos ^2x+\sin ^2x} dx $$ Thus $$I =\frac {\pi}{2}\int \frac {1}{9\cos ^2 x +\sin ^2 x} dx $$ $$=\frac {\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac {\sec^2 x}{9+\tan ^2 x} dx $$ Hope you can finish it up by substituting for $u=\tan x $.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{\sec^2 x}{9+\tan^2 x}dx + \int^{\pi}_{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sec^2 x}{9+\tan^2 x}dx$

Comment: @DURGESH TIWARI I thought the OP should at least know that. That's why I didn't give the hint.